# Get field type in Apache Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

What I'm trying to achieve is a way to detect if the stored value is numeric(`IntPoint` or `FloatPoint`) or string(`StringField` or `TextField`).

For example :
I'm storing this field

```
doc.add(new IntPoint("Value", 4));
```

after I execute a query that return some documents I want to detect if `Value` field type is `IntPoint`

I'm using something like this

```
IndexableField field = doc.getField("Value");
if (field != null)
    System.out.println(field.fieldType());
```

which returns `stored`

If I use `field.fieldType().docValuesType()` it will return  `NONE`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: thats ... a pretty interesting question

Comment: @dom thanks. let me know when you find an answer. I know it's possible because Luke does it. it shows i32(32 bit integer) or i64( 64 bit intger aka Long) or f32 ( float 32 bit)

Comment: What does `field.getClass()` show?

Comment: @Doua i would suggest to reverse engineer luke then ;)

Comment: @DouaBeri where does luke show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what Luke does, hope it helps

```
 public static String fieldFlags(Field fld, FieldInfo info) {
    ...
    Number numeric = null;
    if (fld == null) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
      numeric = fld.numericValue();
    }
    ...
    if (numeric != null) {
      flags.append("#");
      // try faking it
      if (numeric instanceof Integer) {
        flags.append("i32");
      } else if (numeric instanceof Long) {
        flags.append("i64");
      } else if (numeric instanceof Float) {
        flags.append("f32");
      } else if (numeric instanceof Double) {
        flags.append("f64");
      } else if (numeric instanceof Short) {
        flags.append("i16");
      } else if (numeric instanceof Byte) {
        flags.append("i08");
      } else if (numeric instanceof BigDecimal) {
        flags.append("b^d");
      } else if (numeric instanceof BigInteger) {
        flags.append("b^i");
      } else {
        flags.append("???");
      }
      ...
    }
```

[Link to luke code](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/blob/0117b0df6ea3dd660c76e70934128f2d107b3707/src/main/java/org/apache/lucene/luke/app/controllers/dto/documents/DocumentField.java#L121)

Comment: this is exactly what i proposed to do :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here is remark about `IntPoint` field

> An indexed  field for fast range filters.  If you also need to store
>   the value, you should add a separate StoredField instance.

which basically means, I'm not sure, how you get this working:

```
IndexableField field = doc.getField("Value");
```

it should return you `null`, instead of a field.
Also, applicable to all fields - if you're operating on Document returned to your by Lucene - it will only contains fields, which are stored once again.

For stored fields, you could easily get their type by doing something like this:

```
((StoredField) text).fieldsData
```

which would return exactly what's stored there - Float or String or Double.

Another possibility is to call set of methods `stringValue, binaryValue, readerValue, numericValue`, which would return you `String`, `ByteRef`, `Reader` or `Number` or null, if it's not a number, for example.